# UI5: No press event triggered after updating Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, sapui5

For some unknown to me reason, I cannot select `sap.m.IconTabFilter`, like it's not pressable (on mouse hover pointer is not appearing and when I press, nothing happens). This issue is experienced in Chrome. In Mozilla it works fine.

When I copied the XML into JSBin in Chrome, it worked fine.
Did anybody stuck with the same problem? How to fix it?
I tried to clear cache, restart browser/pc - the issue persists.

Also, same issue I'm experiencing right now with `sap.m.Switch` control.

**UPDATE:** I think it's a PC-specific issue. The problem is that in Chrome the app decides it's running on a tablet (instead of a laptop. The laptop can work as tablet too, but I run the app in laptop mode). This applies corresponding app's behavior. Maybe this can be the root of the problem?

No custom CSS is applied, only default ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you are using Chrome 55+ which comes with active PointerEvent and won't work with certain UI5 versions. You need to upgrade to [1.28.42](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.28.42/#versioninfo.html), [1.38.14](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.38.14/#versioninfo.html) or [1.42.8](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.42.8/#versioninfo.html) or deactivate the feature in Chrome via:

`chrome://flags/#enable-pointer-events`

in the address bar.